# Find nearest Neighbour out of N points for M points

Tags: sql, nearest-neighbor

I am currently trying to assign regions to customers by optimizing driving distance.
So far I have generated a from/to/driving time table and for every point withing the problem I am aware in what position they reside.

Thus I have a list a containing customer locations and a list b containing service locations. List be should be assigned to list a.
For me it seems like every point in b should be evaluated on distance to a point in a and then assigned to the closest point.

My question...would there be a way to solve this problem using regular msSQL?

Comment: what is the _question_ can you post input tables with required output ?

Comment: Input table 1= location ID
Input table 2=from location Id,to location ID, travel time

Output table = from location Id,tolocation Id,travel time, assigned location ID (from table 1)

OR Output table = location Id, assigned from location id

Comment: Basically I assume the problem can be reduced to this by filtering out only possible destinations. Per 'from location' I would need to select the minimum travel time to a to location.

Answer (score 0):

Use K-d tree for O(logN) to find the nearest neighbour of any given point . Here if the points are defined as co-ordinates then you can use 2-d tree . Make 2-d tree of the service locations and make query for NN on given customer locations. Note that k-d tree can be used to get nearest neighbor when the distance are euclidean distances but cannot be used for any other random distances.

[K-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)